# Where can I find AutoReviewComments for Firefox?

Tags: support, flagging, comments, 10k-tools

I just got this message in reply to my flag:

> Using AutoReviewComments to add a comment about link-only answers would help out mods. Thanks!

Now, on app page https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se there are links for Chrome and Firefox. But FF link https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/se-autoreviewcomments/ is broken:

> We're sorry, but we can't find what you're looking for.

I understand it was moved, but search https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=auto+review+comments and https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=autoreviewcomments give me no results.

So where can I find it?

Comment: I left that message.  Asking some other mods to see if they know.

Comment: @MPD I don't really care who left it. All I care for is that it is a good advice, but I can't simply use it. I would prefer not to use it as an userscript as GreaseMonkey collided with my other add-ons.

Answer (score 2):

The way I use for now is http://scriptish.org/ add-on with AutoReviewComments as user script. Not ideal solution, but it allows me to avoid Greasemonkey and still use AutoReviewComments when it's native add-on disappeared.

I know scriptish is but a fork of greasemonkey, but it does not conflict with my other addons the way original monkey did, so I can live with it.